# Delete particular items in SharePoint document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to create PowerShell script that will be run daily by time scheduler.
Documents that should be deleted will have Yes value in column1.
Bellow is my code, but I am not sure why it doesn't work

```
$web = get-spweb "URL"
$Libraries = $web.Lists | where {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}
foreach ($library in $Libraries) {
    $items = $library.items
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        If($item["Column1"] -eq "Yes")
        {
            $item.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion what I did wrong?

**EDIT**:
After I ran script it didn't give me any error message, but instead documents weren't deleted.

**EDIT2**: After code edit I got following message:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. At
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\DeleteItems.ps1:5 char:14
>   +     foreach ($item in $items)
>   +              ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: what error message do you got?

Comment: I apologize I didn't write scenario. I will edit question now.

Comment: When you use the debugger are you sure $item.delete() is being called at all?

Comment: Iine 4 should be, $items = $library.items and 
line 5 should be,  foreach ($item in $items)

Comment: Thanks Jatin patil! I missed that. I got error message and will post it in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because you are attempting to delete items from an enumeration inside of a foreach loop.  Most collections in .NET with throw an exception if an item is added or deleted during a foreach loop.

Try a regular for loop and see what happens:

```
$web = get-spweb "URL"
$Libraries = $web.Lists | where {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}
foreach ($library in $Libraries) {
    $items = $library.items
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $items.Count; $i++)
    {
        If($items[$i]["Column1"] -eq "Yes")
        {
            $items[$i].delete()
        }
    }
}
```

That may be enough, but powershell might throw an exception for the outer foreach loop too since technically you're modifying the document libraries inside the loop.  If that is the case, you'll need to use a for loop on the outside too.

Also, one way to speed up your powershell is to use a caml query on the document libraries so that it only returns the items where Column1 = yes (I'm assuming Column1 is a Yes/No field).  That would look like this:

```
$web = get-spweb "URL"
$Libraries = $web.Lists | where {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}
foreach ($library in $Libraries) {
    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Column1'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></Where>"
    $items = $library.GetItems($query)       
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $items.Count; $i++)
    {
        $items[$i].delete()
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Although I thought second version of script will be more suitable for me, it gave me no result. It didn't delete items from any library. But first worked like a charm.

Comment: CAML queries are pretty finicky (and case sensitive) so if anything is a bit off it won't work.  If you wanna get the second version working maybe trying outputing the contents of $items first to make sure that the CAML query is working.  E.g.



    `for ($i=0; $i -lt $items.Count; $i++)
    {
        Write-Host $items[$i].Title
    }`